# Traduzir a descrição do site

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

A descrição do site ainda está em inglês.

> "Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers"

Quando vamos compartilhar nas redes sociais, fica assim:

[image: Descrição]

Uma opção de tradução poderia ser:

> Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas

Comment: Provavelmente relacionada http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92/traducao-incompleta-no-tour-do-site

Comment: Pessoal... eu ia reportar isso também mas bastou uma pesquisadinha aqui para ver que, neste momento, isto já foi reportado CINCO VEZES (pelo menos) aqui no Meta... Ver também: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles?cb=1

Comment: @J.Bruni, eu pesquisei antes de criar este post. Eu decidi postá-lo neste caso específico pois, como estamos em uma fase de divulgação do site, achei interessante criar uma prioridade nisso, que é o nosso cartão de visitas para o mundo externo. Além disso, o bigown já havia me alertado para a questão relacionada. De qualquer forma, não deixa de ser um ponto importante evitarmos a duplicação de conteúdo. Obrigado.

Comment: @VictorHugo - Legal. Quando você reportou, acho que era apenas a segunda ou terceira vez. Se eu não pesquisasse, eu iria reportar pela SEXTA vez! :-) Mas, mesmo não "reportando", apenas fazendo as sinalizações de "duplicado", dando meus "upvotes" e mais esse "barulho" nos comentários... o recado está bem dado! ;-) Obrigado.

Comment: @J.Bruni - E que barulho, hein?! ;) Vale atentar também que, embora sejam relacionadas, a maioria das perguntas repetidas refere-se a uma região diferente do site que ainda não havia sido reportada para tradução. Provavelmente, não observou-se que a pergunta relacionada encobre toda e qualquer questão sobre tradução.

Comment: @VictorHugo: Não entendi. Estes cinco reports (que o meu seria o sexto) referem-se a exatamente o mesmo trecho, que é muito proeminente.

Comment: @VictorHugo: ah, sim, agora vejo que apesar da sentença  a traduzir ser a mesma, dois dos cinco reports a apresentam em contextos diferentes.

Comment: Seja como for, o site me parece estar indo muito bem. Só merece ser parabenizado. Obrigado!

Comment: @J.Bruni: obrigado a você por se juntar a nossa comunidade e estar ajudando. Desculpe qualquer coisa